# Unable to separate metadata to different strings

Tags: iphone, ios, metadata, audio-streaming

The metadata that is being retrieved in a different set of code is being displayed on the on the screen on the same string with a " - " separating them. How do I get each of the sets of info onto their own line or string?

```
    NSDictionary *currentlyPlayingTrackInfo;
    NSString *msg = albumInfo;
    NSString *newArtist;
    NSString *newSongName;

    NSRange range = [msg rangeOfString:@" - "];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound){
        newArtist = [msg substringToIndex:range.location];
        newSongName = [msg substringFromIndex:(range.location + range.length)];
    }

    if (newArtist != nil){
        currentlyPlayingTrackInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newArtist, newSongName, pmAlbumArt, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork, nil]];
    }else{
        currentlyPlayingTrackInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:msg, pmAlbumArt, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork, nil]];
    }
    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = currentlyPlayingTrackInfo;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: It is displaying the artist, title, and album fine its just that right now when they are displayed on one line and I would rather have them all on their own lines to keep them more individual. Not sure if that makes sense. I suppose just a style preference :)

Comment: How are you displaying them? It looks like you got the strings separated into two, ok.

Comment: Well, right now the string looks like " artist - title - album " but what is desired is  " artist **/next line below artist/** title **/next line below title/** album ". If you can understand that.

Comment: Yes, I know what you want. What I don't understand is what's not working. The code you have above separates the string into 2 strings, right? Is that not working? Does msg contain artist - title - album? It looks like you're only separating the first 2.

Comment: Hmmm...the demo version of the code I bought is found here [link]http://stormyprods.com/Demos/RadioKitARC-4.5-Demo.zip If that helps at all. What I do Know is that it is displaying all the info of the current song. How it is I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep msg as one string, you could just replace the "-" with a "\n", and that will break it into 3 lines.

```
    NSString *s = @"Artist - Song - Album";
    NSString *newString = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```